# Better way to replace all values from column values pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am looking for a better way to replace all column values with some other value.

What I currently have is this:

```
gender_text = ['undefined', 'male', 'female']

df.loc[df['gender'] == 0, 'gender'] = gender_text[0]
df.loc[df['gender'] == 1, 'gender'] = gender_text[1]
df.loc[df['gender'] == 2, 'gender'] = gender_text[2]

df.head()
```

I was hoping for something a bit more elegant and use the `gender` value (0, 1 or 2) as the index to choose from in `gender_text` to have everything fit in one line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a dictionary.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'gender':[0,0,2,1,1,2]})

gender_text = {0:'undefined', 1:'male', 2:'female'}
df['gender'].map(gender_text)

# Out[33]: 
# 0    undefined
# 1    undefined
# 2       female
# 3         male
# 4         male
# 5       female
# Name: gender, dtype: object
```

Alternatively, you can also `pd.merge`, which might be better for larger datasets.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'gender':[0,0,2,1,1,2]})
df_map = pd.DataFrame({'gender': [0, 1, 2], 'gender_new': ['undefined', 'male', 'female']})

df['gender'] = df.merge(df_map, on=['gender'])['gender_new']
```

Answer (score 2):

You can define a `dict`

```
replace_values = {0 :'undefined', 1 : 'male', 2 : 'female'}
```

And replace multiple values using `replace`

```
df = df.replace({"gender": replace_values})
```

Alternatively, replace each value in the column using

```
df.gender = df.gender.replace(0, 'undefined')
df.gender = df.gender.replace(1, 'male')
df.gender = df.gender.replace(2, 'female')
```

Answer (score 2):

This is one of the usecase of the `map` function (use **`np.select`** for much faster performance)-

```
gender_text  = {0 :'undefined', 1 : 'male', 2 : 'female'}
df['gender'] = df['gender'].map(gender_text)
```

Or you can use `apply` -

```
df['gender'] =  df['gender'].apply(lambda x :  gender_text[x])
```

Or you can use **`np.select`**

```
condlist = [df['gender'] == 0,
            df['gender'] == 1,
            df['gender'] == 2]

choicelist = ['undefined',
              'male',
              'female']
df['gender'] = np.select(condlist, choicelist)
```

**`Performace Comparison`**. — >

```
%timeit df['gender'] = df['gender'].map(gender_text)
411 µs ± 10.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit df['gender'] = np.select(condlist,choicelist)
101 µs ± 322 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```